# What is difference between ZoomTo and ZoomBy in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

Currently, I am working with google map and may have confusion between this two methods. I don't differentiate working of this two method so, can anyone explain me what is difference between zoomBy() and zoomTo()

**Code:**

```
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(zoomLevel));
mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoomLevel));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(float) gives you a CameraUpdate that
>   changes the zoom level to the given value, while keeping all other
>   properties the same.
>
> CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(float) and
>   CameraUpdateFactory.zoomBy(float, Point) give you a CameraUpdate that
>   increases (or decreases, if the value is negative) the zoom level by
>   the given value. The latter fixes the given point on the screen such
>   that it remains at the same location (latitude/longitude) and so it
>   may change the location of the camera in order to achieve this.

From official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views)

So in short zoomTo just changes the zoom level to the given value, while the zoomBy increases or decreases ( e.g. with zoomTo(20) your camera will have the zoom level set to 20, but if your zoom level was 20 and you call zoomBy(-5), your zoom level will become 15)

Comment: you last three line important for me comparatively documentation statements.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static CameraUpdate zoomBy (float amount, Point focus)
```

> Returns a `CameraUpdate` that shifts the zoom level of the current
>   camera viewpoint.
>
> A point specified by focus will remain fixed (i.e., it corresponds to
>   the same lat/long both before and after the zoom process).
>
> This method is different to zoomTo(float) in that zoom is relative to
>   the current camera.
>
> For example, if the LatLng (11.11, 22.22) is currently at the screen
>   location (23, 45). After calling this method with a zoom amount and
>   this LatLng, the screen location of this LatLng will still be (23,
>   45).

```
public static CameraUpdate zoomTo (float zoom)
```

> Returns a CameraUpdate that moves the camera viewpoint to a particular
>   zoom level.